# SQL Query Problem in Inline Query in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

My sql table structure is this

```
ID  DataName
1   Lipsum lorem 
3   lipsum's lorem
```

My inline query in asp.net is that

```
select * from table where DataName like 'lipsum's lorem'
```

It gives the following errors:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 's'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.
```

I don't want to create a stored procedure to prevent this, I want a solution to this using inline queries.

Comment: Does `'lipsum's lorem'` come from user supplied input that you are concatenating into the query?

Comment: yes it comes from user supplied

Comment: Well in that case you are wide open for SQL injection at the moment. You should use parameterised queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should look like...

```
select * from table where DataName like 'lipsum''s lorem'
```

As you need to escape the `' to '`  to get it to work.

For more details check out this link: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/17/sql-server-how-to-escape-single-quotes-fix-error-105-unclosed-quotation-mark-after-the-character-string/

If you use `Command Parameters`, check this link out:

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the `'` in 'lipsum's lorem'

`'lipsum''s lorem'`

But the real fix is to a use parameterised query, to prevent SQL injection.

`SqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DataName = @DataName";`

In your command object add a parameter for @DataName with its value.

`SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataName", Value);`

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the **Single Quote with Double Quote**

```
String.replace("'", "''")
```

That means put the search string in the string variable and replace the single quote with double quote

```
string str = "lipsum's lorem"
str.Replace("'", "''")
```

Comment: The problem is using replace instead of a command from a DB library that escapes parameters for you.

Comment: Just leave it @Eric. I even forgot it. :)

Comment: By the way I got to know from your repulation history. :) http://stackoverflow.com/users/57611/erik?tab=reputation

Answer (score 0):

ID  DataName

1   Lipsum lorem

3   lipsum's lorem

**select * from table where DataName like 'lipsum''s lorem'**

or

**select * from table where DataName='lipsum''s lorem'**

**select * from table where DataName like'lipsum%' (To select both rows)**

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameterized query.

```
var command = new SqlCommand()
    {
        CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE DataName = @dataName",
        Parameters = { { "@dataName", "lipsum's lorem" } }
    }
```